# I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I cannot figure this simple system out

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    <?php
        $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","eme");

        if($db->connect_errno){ echo "Not connected."; exit();}

        echo $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") . "<br>";
        echo $_POST[FirstName] . " " . $_POST[LastName];
        $db->query("INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$_POST[FirstName]','$_POST[LastName]')");
        echo $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") . "<br>";

    ?>
```

I cannot figure out why this code doesn't work. The only line that outputs anything is "echo $_POST[FirstName] . " " . $_POST[LastName];"

My database has a "users" table and the database is called eme. The database connects properly.

There is currently no data in the database. I figured I could add some with "INSERT," but it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

The query() method of mysqli returns a [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. you need to use one of it's methods to get the actual data back from the query.  For instance [fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

In your insert, you need to either assign `$_POST['FirstName']` to a variable, or explicitly add it to the string.

ie.

```
"INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('" . $_POST['FirstName'] . "','" . $_POST['LastName'] . "')"
```

or

```
$first = $_POST['FirstName'];
$last = $_POST['LastName'];
"INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('" . $first . "', '" . $last . "')"
```

You should also [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the data before inserting it to prevent major security threats.

Lastly, it's not a bug per se, but you should always use a string or integer value for an array index.

ie. You have `$_POST[FirstName]`, it should be either `$_POST['FirstName']` or `$_POST["FirstName"]`

It will still work, but the interpreter thinks it's a constant, which isn't defined, so assumes the literal value, throwing a warning (maybe notice, can't remember offhand).  It's unnecessary overhead.

Comment: That's very helpful. I did not know about mysqli_result objects and using fetch_assoc. Now I am well versed in it. Also, security will be a concern, so thanks for mentioning that. I tried assigning the values to variables first and it works fine without the periods or nested quotes. However, if I try to use $_POST[] in the query, I need the periods. Why do I need the periods?

Comment: It has to do with how strings work in PHP.  If you have `$var = "something"; echo "$var";`  PHP will parse $var in the string.  However if you have `echo "$_POST['var']";`, it is ambiguous if PHP should parse `"$_POST"` or `"$_POST['var']"`.  iirc you can do `"{$_POST['var']}"` instead of doing `"" . $_POST['var'] . " post";` ("" being used for demonstrating, you don't need to put blank string like that anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES('".$_POST['FirstName']."','".$_POST['LastName']."')");
```

For more info on `Quotes`, look over this link - [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/1288198)

Comment: Why are there extra periods. Why are there single quotes encapsulating double quotes? And is the W3 site wrong? (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Also, when I edited to that, the line `echo $_POST[FirstName] . " " . $_POST[LastName];` now does not output anything, even if I comment out the $db->query line or reverse it back to the original. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Now try `echo '$_POST[FirstName]' . " " . '$_POST[LastName]';`. Go to the link I have pasted, it has a nice explanation.

Comment: That echo worked! It turned out, I could write `$db->query("INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$_POST[FirstName]' , '$_POST[LastName]')")`